# Spring data jpa, rest application connecting to multiple databases - getting Connection is closed after idle time

Tags: spring-data-jpa, database-connection, datasource

I am using Spring boot version 1.5.4.RELEASE. My database is DB2.

In my application I am connecting to multiple databases as defined in below article.

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

when I run /health on my application I am getting below error

```
{
    status: "DOWN",
    diskSpace: {
        status: "UP",
        total: 10722738176,
        free: 10123337728,
        threshold: 10485760
    },
    db: {
        status: "DOWN",
        dataSource2: {
            status: "UP",
            database: "DB2/AIX64",
            hello: 1
        },
        dataSource1: {
            status: "DOWN",
            error: "org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: ConnectionCallback; SQL []; [jcc][t4][10335][10366][4.19.26] Invalid operation: Connection is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=08003; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][10335][10366][4.19.26] Invalid operation: Connection is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=08003"
        }
    }
}
```